# Is zookeeper compulsory for Distributed mode (hadoop cluster 1.x version) to configure Hbase on it?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have only 2 node cluster(distrbuted) having hadoop 1.2.0. I want to configure hbase(0.94.10) on top it . Is configuring zookeeper compulsory for this configuration- for distributed mode?

For Standalone mode Zk is managed by hbase and it runs perfectly fine, but in distributed mode I have to use external Zk to make hbase runnning.
I have heard that Zk is not compulsory for hadoop 1.x version to configure hbase on top of it even in distributed mode. is it true?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the question?

Setting up a cluster which has just Hadoop is different from setting up a HBase cluster. You don't need ZK in order to have a Hadoop(alone) cluster. But, ZK is a must if you are planning to have HBase running on top of it, be it a **1 node** HBase setup or **n node** HBase setup.

A distributed Hadoop setup doesn't imply that it has got HBase setup as well. A Hadoop cluster is just a Hadoop cluster, while a HBase cluster means that you have a Hadoop layer underneath it(normally).

P.S. : Please update your question if you still have any query as I am a bit confused by the heading of your question and the actual question.